# How to remove line-breaks and whitespaces from an XML signed with javax.xml.crypto API

Tags: java, xml, signature, xml-signature

I'm working with the mexican "factura Electronica", and I need to sign an XML document with cert.cer and key.key files,

but the requirement is that there are absolutely no whitespaces and line-breaks between tags, including signature tags().

**And if I remove the line-breaks and whitespaces after signing, the signature gets broken** and
I cannot change the canonicalizer / transformers set either, since they're predefined.

***I'm signing the XML document with the javax.xml.crypto API**

**Below is the code:**

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null, null);

    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
            fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(ref));


    X509Certificate cert = KeyLoaderFactory.createInstance(KeyLoaderEnumeration.PUBLIC_KEY_LOADER, new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Desktop\\PEMS\\Certificado\\0000166600201052508s.cer")).getKey();

    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List x509Content = new ArrayList();

    X509IssuerSerial issuer = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getIssuerDN().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());
    x509Content.add(issuer);
    x509Content.add(cert);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AdminFraccionamientoWeb1\\web\\assets\\Pdfs\\Cancel_" + UUID + ".xml"));

    PrivateKey privateKey = KeyLoaderFactory.createInstance(KeyLoaderEnumeration.PRIVATE_KEY_LOADER, new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Desktop\\PEMS\\Certificado\\DST1010185B7_1205106666S.key"), "Suport").getKey();

    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());

    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    signature.sign(dsc);
    String Ruta = "C:\\Users\\Arturo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AdminFraccionamientoWeb1\\web\\assets\\Pdfs\\Cancel_signed" + UUID + ".xml";

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Ruta);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

**And below is the resulting signature**

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>  
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>    
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/> </Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>DiLnrOczxtHVnhG4EA9zj0JM8O0=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>PrHxWCpnZlFi92ETs0JMnVML/FoUxQkktRT5UpU9W90DhKZFX31nFjwEtt3GBluz+xEdt+j4lmnd
JHdZbEynVwqsm5ZF2Y/Z34fn/f050pUXyjitlog8QWoKB+oCbaNW1L3+9VHyuKQ4t/1XbNt6RCgM
RkDEm4hDc6V55G/szIQ=
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509IssuerSerial>   
<X509IssuerName>OID.1.2.840.113549.1.9.2=Responsable: Cecilia Guillermina García   Guerra, OID.2.5.4.45=SAT970701NN3, L=Cuauhtémoc, ST=Distrito Federal, C=MX,   OID.2.5.4.17=06300, STREET="Av. Hidalgo 77, Col. Guerrero",   EMAILADDRESS=asisnet@sat.gob.mx, OU=Administración de Seguridad de la   Información, O=Servicio de Administración Tributaria, CN=A.C. del Servicio de   Administración Tributaria
</X509IssuerName>   
<X509SerialNumber>275106190557734483187066766774039086286478061624
</X509SerialNumber>
</X509IssuerSerial>  
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Notice the unwanted line-breaks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simple answer:  Ask the chimpanzees at factura Electronica how they produce the signature files without whitespace.  Note: chimpanzee is the nicest description for a group of idiot primate programmers who are unable to ignore whitespace in xml.

Comment: They claim that they stated this rule in order to reduce the network traffic (which is actually huge), since some softwares were including abusive amounts of indentation whitespaces. They are able to verify the signature successfully. There's this other rule that is applied which incurs in the rejection of the message.

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours , i've  found a solution to my problem.
I hope this works for someone else.

We just need to set the "true" value to the "ignoreLineBreaks" parameter,
cause' the default value is false and this allows to the signature API to add LineBreaks

here is the code to avoid or remove LineBreaks

```
Field f = XMLUtils.class.getDeclaredField("ignoreLineBreaks");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(null, Boolean.TRUE);
```

then, we'll can make sure that the new value is true with the next code line

```
System.err.println(XMLUtils.ignoreLineBreaks());
```

Comment: It has been a long time after the solution has been added here and I guess I would need to do something similar in my code. However I am unable to understand how and where the solution fits in the code shared in the question and what additional libraries will be required for the same.

Comment: I had the same question

Comment: It use `org.apache.santuario`.
You also can:`String xmlSec = "org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks";
        System.setProperty(xmlSec, "true");`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove any white spaces including line-breaks, tabs, and new line etc using a text editor such as Notepad++. Below is a snapshot showing the extended characters that can be used to remove these white spaces. [Replace tab in notepad++ text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chaCj.png)

Comment: if do that  the signature gets broken.

Comment: Did you try removing the white spaces before signing the xml document ?

Comment: If I remove the spaces from the signature afterwards, the signature unavoidably gets broken.

Comment: If I am not wrong, that's the sole purpose of signing a document that noone should be able to change anything once it is signed. That's why I was asking that you should remove the white spaces if need to be before signing the document.